# Error when using web workers with Angular, transpiler removes a piece of code

Tags: angular, webpack, web-worker

I've got the following code in my Angular application:

```
      const worker = new Worker("./filter.worker.ts", {
        type: "module",
      });
```

Which Angular transpiles to the following:

```
  var worker = new Worker(__webpack__worker__0, {
            ,
        });
```

And that gives me an error in the browser
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','`

I have the following versions of angular packages:

```
  "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
  "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
  "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
  "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.25",
  "@angular/cli": "^8.3.25",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
  "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing the comma:

```
const worker = new Worker("./filter.worker.ts", {type: "module"});
```